# Microsoft Web Browser Active X broken

Tags: internet-explorer, ms-access, activex

Recent windows updates seem to have broken the MS Web Browser Active X control.  I found Stephen Labens HTML Editor (http://www.lebans.com/htmleditor.htm) as a demonstration and downloaded it.  As in my own application the message is "no object in this control".

I'm using Access 2003 on a Win XP machine.  My version of shDocVw.dll (Internet Controls) is 6.0.2900.5803.  I rolled back to 6.0.2900.5770 but it was still broken.  The client I developed the software for in April 2009 is still running ok and has version 6.0.3790.4098 of the file on a server.

Has anyone else had this issue or know of any potential fixes?

When I try to add the control to a new form I get the message: Microsoft Office Access doesn't support this ActiveX Control.

I don't have VB6 installed.  I'm using Access 2003.  I also have the Office 2007 suite installed and SQL Server 2008.

UPDATE 28th June: Today I turned on my notebook which had been off for a month or so.  I installed all the office updates and then went through the other updates one by one.

961501 WinXP
968537 WinXP
969897 IE6 (this one updated shdocvw.dll to 6.0.2900.5803
969898 Killbits
970238 WinXP

After all these updates the Web Browser activeX works!!  I have also checked on my home PC where all updates had installed automatically and the activeX works fine.  So my main work PC must just have had something go wrong along the way.  The only really different piece of software on my work PC is the Symantec Client VPN software (9.0.0.1825) which interferes with my networking in other ways.

Comment: Have you deleted the control and re-inserted it after you rolled back to the previous version?

Comment: I get the message - Microsoft Office Access doesn't support this ActiveX Control

Answer (score 0):

This?

[Microsoft Security Advisory (960715) Update Rollup for ActiveX Kill Bits](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/advisory/960715.mspx)

FWIW I had a similar issue with a MS DataGrid control in Excel where the fix was to download and install Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 Service Pack 6 Cumulative Update. Here's the [Usenet thread](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/microsoft.public.office.developer.vba/tree/browse_frm/thread/0ff03d45c761a906/24a285a5e4e113d6?hl=en&rnum=1&_done=%2Fgroup%2Fmicrosoft.public.office.developer.vba%2Fbrowse_frm%2Fthread%2Fff03d45c761a906%2Fdebe76c8649ba974%3Fhl%3Den%26#doc_debe76c8649ba974).

Comment: I don't think so - the update states "This update contains kill bits for third-party controls not owned by Microsoft".  As far as I can tell I'm only working with Microsoft products here.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It's hitting MS controls, too. There was a recent thread in one of the MS Public.Access newsgroups about someone doing serial port I/O with an MS DLL that the kill bits patch broke.

Comment: Mark 960715 might not be the article mentioning the MS Web Browser control but if you follow up on the link to Microsoft Security Bulletin MS08-070 - Critical http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/Bulletin/ms08-070.mspx it mentions lots of MS controls.

So you'll need to locate and download the latest version.  Then figure out how to distribute it.

Comment: David, the nice thing about the serial port I/O is I had previously located a link to API code which removed the need for the control in the first place.  Trouble is that won't work for the Web Browser.  <sigh>

Comment: I tried both 957924 and 926857 but they both require VB6 to be installed.  Thanks for all the help so far.  Tony - I'm not sure where to go with that Security Bulletin.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be Description of the cumulative update rollup for the Visual Basic 6.0 Service Pack 6 Runtime Extended Files  http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=957924  although doesn't mention shDocVw.dll.

I gotta say I'm quite confused by what files are updated by which security update, etc, etc, etc.  Mind numbing.  And I'm reasonably good at reading MS stuff.

Comment: I tried but was advised that I can't install the update since I don't have VB6 installed.

Comment: Darn.  Ok, I've sent an email to my contacts within Microsoft on this problem.   Dunno if and when I'll get a useful answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with depending on some of the built-in ActiveX components, including the browser component.  I'm now using a 3rd party ActiveX component, the [nBit HTML Viewer](http://www.nbit.net.au/vPages.aspx?ID=HTML%20Viewer%20ActiveX) for my commercial app with 10,000+ installs.

While it's not free, it's only $24.95 and that's enough to pay for one support call with someone who hasn't run Windows Update if I'm using the MS component.